# Doubt about validation in WinForm application

Tags: winforms

I'm creating my first application in WindowsForms and wondered how I would do to validate the User input logic layer and return to the textbox control such that he filled out incorrectly by ErrorProvider. That is, each would have to return the validation error for each specific control indicating whether the user typed an invalid value.

This is a good practice?

Today, this validation is done on the presentation layer and would like to use my more logical layer so that she is not only acting as an intermediary between the presentation and data access.

Comment: Yes, it is a good practice to validate user input.  Obviously.  Do you have a real question?

Comment: I would like to bring to each control logic layer to validate and then return the error?

Comment: What does that mean? How are you going to present the error to the user without using the presentation layer?

Comment: As happened in the validation logic layer, I need to indicate to the User (presentation layer) typed it wrong, so I need to access the textbox in the middle tier, that's my question, how do I access each separate textbox and return the error in a single call validation

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to maintain separation of concerns you should look into implementing the model-view-controller design pattern.  This will allow you to keep you UI code cleaner

**Overview of MVC**

- **Model**

  - Contains state and implementation
  - Notifies listeners (views) of changes
- **View**

  - Displays model state (and responds to model state notifications)
  - Send all user input to the controller
- **Controller**

  - Processes all input from the view
  - Changes model state and calls model methods
  - Load a different view as needed

**Further Reading**

- http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller